# how can i control gpu number when using TrainingArguments

Tags: huggingface, large-language-model, huggingface-trainer

Im working on multi GPU server and i want to use one GPU for the training
setting GPU for the train

```
device = torch.device("cuda:2")
torch.cuda.set_device(device)

device_map={"": torch.cuda.current_device()}

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    model_path,
    quantization_config=bnb_config,
    device_map=device_map
)

model.config.use_cache = False
model.config.pretraining_tp = 1
```

but as soon as i run the TrainingArguments() part the torch.cuda.current_device() has changed to 0

```
training_arguments = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    num_train_epochs=num_train_epochs,
    per_device_train_batch_size=per_device_train_batch_size,
    gradient_accumulation_steps=gradient_accumulation_steps,
    optim=optim,
    save_steps=save_steps,
    logging_steps=logging_steps,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    weight_decay=weight_decay,
    fp16=fp16,
    bf16=bf16,
    max_grad_norm=max_grad_norm,
    max_steps=max_steps,
    warmup_ratio=warmup_ratio,
    group_by_length=group_by_length,
    lr_scheduler_type=lr_scheduler_type,
    report_to=["tensorboard"] 
)
```

how can i maintain GPU number